# javafx: enable button during runtime

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to enable a disabled button once user input is validated. Any ideas on how I can make it to work?

```
@FXML
public void validate(KeyEvent event) {
    Register validate = new Register();
    if(validate.authentication(usernameTxt.getText(), passwordTxt.getText(), repasswordTxt.getText())) {
        next.setDisable(false); // <-- LINE 57
    }
}
```

> -
>       Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at controllers.RegisterController.validate(RegisterController.java:57)

Comment: Which line is line 57?

Comment: Have you make sure that every field (usernameTxt, passwordTxt and repasswordTxt) is annotated with `@FXML` and in the .fxml file the controls have exactly the same id (set with `fx:id="usernameTxt"` etc.)?

Comment: yes they have annotations

Comment: Ensure you have imported `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent` and not `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`.

Comment: Your "next" button must also be annotated and match fx:id..